# How to remove space from the end of %~dp0 in batch file in windows 10

Tags: windows, batch

I have this batch file:

```
set LOCAL_ROOT="%~dp0" 
setx BOOST_ROOT             "%LOCAL_ROOT%\boost"
```

when I run this batch file, I am getting this value set to BOOST_ROOT

```
BOOST_ROOT=D:\Local\ boost
```

as can be seen, there is a space in path which should not exist. How can I remove it?

Comment: [How to get the path of a batch script without the trailing backslash in a single command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3160058/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
@echo off
set LOCAL_ROOT=%~dp0
setx BOOST_ROOT="%LOCAL_ROOT%boost"

REM the next two lines are for debugging, remove from final batch file:
echo %BOOST_ROOT%
pause
```

Alternatively, without declaring the first variable at all:

```
@echo off
setx BOOST_ROOT="%~dp0boost"
```

You don't need the quotes while declaring `LOCAL_ROOT`, and your code appears to have a few formatting errors. Keep in mind that `%~dp0` includes a trailing backslash.